# Single quote issue while creating the query for BCP utility

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am stuck in bcp query string formatting issue. I am missing one quote somewhere and unable to find it out. Here is my code:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @stmt_c varchar(1000);
DECLARE @Current_Database varchar(1000) = (SELECT DB_NAME());
DECLARE @YYYYMMDD varchar(1000) = (SELECT convert(varchar, GETDATE(), 112));
DECLARE @YYYYMMDDhhmmss varchar(1000) = (SELECT format(getdate(),'yyyyMMddHHmmss'));
DECLARE @location varchar(1000) = 'D:\BackUp 2\Data\';
DECLARE @filename varchar(1000) = 'TGF_'+@YYYYMMDDhhmmss+'_'+@YYYYMMDD+'_'+'TT.dat';
DECLARE @absPath varchar(1000) = @location+@filename;
DECLARE @recordCount varchar(1000) = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM data_v);
DECLARE @totalBytes varchar(1000) = (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(LEN(result)),0) FROM data_v);
DECLARE @totalItems varchar(1000) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ITEM_ID) FROM ITEM_TX);
DECLARE @totalChgd varchar(1000) = '0.00000';
DECLARE @trailer varchar(1000) = 'SELECT ''TRAILER''+''|''+@recordCount+''|''+@totalBytes+''|''+@totalChgd+''|''+@totalItems';

SET @stmt_c=
    'BCP '+
     '"SELECT ''HEADER|AA|'+@YYYYMMDDhhmmss+'|'+@YYYYMMDD+'|1.0'' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM data_v UNION ALL '+ @trailer" '+
    'QUERYOUT "'+@absPath+'" '+
    '-c -t, -T -d ' + @Current_Database;
EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell @stmt_c;

END
```

The above code is giving me the following error:

```
Incorrect syntax near ' '+
    'QUERYOUT '.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' '+
    '-c -t, -T -d ' + @Current_Database;
EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell @stmt_c;

END 
'.
```

I want to export result set of the following query:

```
SELECT 'HEADER|AA|'+@YYYYMMDDhhmmss+'|'+@YYYYMMDD+'|1.0' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM data_v UNION ALL SELECT 'TRAILER|'+@recordCount+'|'+@totalBytes+'|'+@totalChgdPrem+'|'+@totalPolicies
```

I am not able to append the trailer query in my code.

Comment: so do you get an error ? or what is the problem ?

Comment: Seems like you need to be properly quoting your values. if they're 128 characters or less in length, `QUOTENAME` will help you here. If not, you can use `REPLACE` to "double up" the single quotes.

Comment: I have updated my question with the error message.

Comment: do a `PRINT @stmt_c` and check

Comment: The control won't reach the PRINT statement. The program failes in SET @stmt_c line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue.

Commented the @trailer variable.

```
-- DECLARE @trailer varchar(1000) = 'SELECT ''TRAILER''+''|''+@recordCount+''|''+@totalBytes+''|''+@totalChgd+''|''+@totalItems';
```

Modifiled the query string to:

```
'"SELECT ''HEADER|AA|'+@YYYYMMDDhhmmss+'|'+@YYYYMMDD+'|1.0'' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM data_v UNION ALL SELECT ''TRAILER|'+@recordCount+'|'+@totalBytes+'|'+@totalChgd+'|'+@totalItems+'''" '
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to print out the string now.
I have had edited the statement where you fetch data from table "data_v" (which I do not have access to) so that it will work at my end. At your end it should work with the original code.

Now it will also execute the other statements.

Please try this:

```
    BEGIN
DECLARE @stmt_c varchar(1000);
DECLARE @Current_Database varchar(1000) = (SELECT DB_NAME());
DECLARE @YYYYMMDD varchar(1000) = (SELECT convert(varchar, GETDATE(), 112));
DECLARE @YYYYMMDDhhmmss varchar(1000) = (SELECT format(getdate(),'yyyyMMddHHmmss'));
DECLARE @location varchar(1000) = 'D:\BackUp 2\Data\';
DECLARE @filename varchar(1000) = 'TGF_'+@YYYYMMDDhhmmss+'_'+@YYYYMMDD+'_'+'TT.dat';
DECLARE @absPath varchar(1000) = @location+@filename;
DECLARE @recordCount varchar(1000) = (SELECT '369' as col);
DECLARE @totalBytes varchar(1000) = (SELECT '674' as col);
DECLARE @totalItems varchar(1000) = (SELECT '14' as col);
DECLARE @totalChgd varchar(1000) = '0.00000';
DECLARE @trailer varchar(1000) = 'SELECT ''TRAILER|'+@recordCount+'|'+@totalBytes+'|'+@totalChgd+'|'+@totalItems;

SET @stmt_c=
    'BCP '+
        '"SELECT ''HEADER|AA|'+@YYYYMMDDhhmmss+'|'+@YYYYMMDD+'|1.0'' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM data_v UNION ALL '+ @trailer+'" '+
    'QUERYOUT "'+@absPath+'" '+
    '-c -t, -T -d ' + @Current_Database;
print @stmt_c

--EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell @stmt_c;

END
```

Here is the result at my end:

```
BCP "SELECT 'HEADER|AA|20190705154946|20190705|1.0' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM data_v UNION ALL SELECT 'TRAILER|369|674|0.00000|14" QUERYOUT "D:\BackUp 2\Data\TGF_20190705154946_20190705_TT.dat" -c -t, -T -d master
```

edit:
As you have mentioned, that you have solved the issue, would be greatr to enhance this question with your solution, or if you don`t want to, pleasee delete the whole question.

Comment: This output has not replaced the variables with their values in the Trailer. 
Correct output would be:
BCP "SELECT 'HEADER|AA|20190704174650|20190704|1.0' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM data_V UNION ALL SELECT '|TRAILER|369|674|0.00000|14'"

Comment: but maybe it is only becaus of I do not have access to your db. To run the script at my end, I had to comment the desired parts, therefore they are not as expected. Have you tried to run the code at your end now?

Comment: Still the variables are not replaced by their values. However, I fixed the issue. Thanks for the help Matt.